# What it means "A breaks B and and is installed" while compiling and installing apt pkg in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg, checkinstall

I have an apt package that is compiled for Ubuntu 13.04 and want to install it on Ubuntu 14.04
The package in question depends on `libcogl12` which is not available on Ubuntu 14.04 (replaced by newer libcogl15 as i assume).

In order to solve this problem i download cogl source code and build libcogl12 manually:

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev libxcomposite-dev libglib2.0-dev libpango1.0-dev
curl -O http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/cogl/1.7/cogl-1.7.8.tar.xz
cd cogl-1.7.8
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
sudo checkinstall
```

In `checkinstall` interactive menu i define a `libcogl12` name for resulting package. It is built without problems, but upon install i got an error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcogl12:
 libclutter-1.0-0:amd64 (1.16.4-0ubuntu2) breaks libcogl12 and is installed.
```

What this "A breaks B and is installed" means? I can't see any documentation for such errors :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from here: http://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.package-meta-information.html

> 5.2.1.3. Incompatibilities: the Breaks Field
>
> The Breaks field has an effect similar to that of the Conflicts field, but with a special
> meaning. It signals that the installation of a package will “break”
> another package (or particular versions of it). In general, this
> incompatibility between two packages is transitory, and the Breaks
> relationship specifically refers to the incompatible versions. dpkg
> will refuse to install a package that breaks an already installed
> package, and apt-get will try to resolve the problem by updating the
> package that would be broken to a newer version (which is assumed to
> be fixed and, thus, compatible again). This type of situation may
> occur in the case of updates without backwards compatibility: this is
> the case if the new version no longer functions with the older
> version, and causes a malfunction in another program without making
> special provisions. The Breaks field prevents the user from running
> into these problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Bot what "break" exactly means? Do both packages trying to install different files with same name? Or what? Is it any way to find a reason for "break"?

Comment: That's left to the implementer of the "break" flag :) Basically yeah, different file versions with the same location, different libraries with the same name, whatnot.. If you know that package A will break package B, you just add it in that breaks field :) Details are left to the packager.